# Restoring from PostgreSQL 9.5 dump to 10 is super slow

Tags: postgresql, restore, postgresql-9.5, postgresql-10, pg-restore

I am trying to restore database dump created on PostgreSQL 9.5.16 to PostgreSQL 10.7 and it is taking a lot of time to restore. Restoring the same dump to 9.5 doesn't take that much. So I am wondering what could be reason behind this slowness.

Some numbers to show how slow it is:

- Small tables (<500MB):

  - 9.5 to 9.5 took 1m4.110s
  - 9.5 to 10 took 1m4.575s
- Medium tables (500MB to 5GB):

  - 9.5 to 9.5 took 6m53.132s
  - 9.5 to 10 took 6m0.998s
- Large tables (5GB+):

  - 9.5 to 9.5 took **131m35.106s**
  - 9.5 to 10 took **831m25.539s**

Underlying hardware and OS used in both cases are exactly the same.

Thinking that there could be data format difference between Postgres 9.5 and 10  and that could be the reason to this slowness, I tried dumping from Postgres 10 and restoring it on Postgres 10, but that is also super slow.

Here are some numbers of that:

- Small tables (<500MB):

  - 10 to 10 took 0m51.248s
- Medium tables (500MB to 5GB):

  - 10 to 10 took 5m40.224s
- Large tables (5GB+):

  - 10 to 10 took **832m36.850s**

#### Restore commands

The commands I am using to restore:

```
pg_restore -v -F d -n public -U <user> -d <database> -h localhost -j 4 --disable-triggers -e -L <file with table names> /var/lib/pgsql/20190425/pg_dump_data
```

#### Hardware characteristics

The hardware I am running on:

- CPU: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2686 v4 @ 2.30GHz (2 cores)
- Memory: 16GB
- HDD: nvme 300GB
- FS: ext4

#### Postgres settings

Postgres configuration that I have on this setup:

```
shared_buffers = 128MB

work_mem             = 1MB
maintenance_work_mem = 16MB
dynamic_shared_memory_type = posix

huge_pages     = try
vacuum_cost_page_hit   = 1
vacuum_cost_page_miss  = 10
vacuum_cost_page_dirty = 20
bgwriter_lru_maxpages   = 100
full_page_writes = on
seq_page_cost        = 1.0
random_page_cost     = 4.0

wal_level = minimal
wal_sync_method = fsync
wal_log_hints    = off
wal_buffers      = -1
wal_writer_delay = 200ms
min_wal_size                 = 1GB
max_wal_size                 = 80GB
max_wal_senders    = 0
wal_keep_segments  = 0
wal_sender_timeout = 60s
wal_receiver_status_interval = 10s
wal_receiver_timeout = 60s

autovacuum = on
log_autovacuum_min_duration = -1
autovacuum_max_workers = 3
autovacuum_naptime = 1min
autovacuum_vacuum_threshold = 50
autovacuum_analyze_threshold = 50
autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor = 0.2
autovacuum_analyze_scale_factor = 0.1
autovacuum_freeze_max_age = 200000000
autovacuum_multixact_freeze_max_age = 400000000
autovacuum_vacuum_cost_delay = 20ms
autovacuum_vacuum_cost_limit = -1
```

#### Considerations

Some more things observed:

- Running strace on Postgres process showed continuous stream of lseek/read/write calls and it also showed bunch of futex wait and resume calls. These futex calls are not easily seen on Postgres 9.5
- Looking at `pg_stat_activity` table showed WALWriteLock under `wait_event` column. It used to change but could see this coming up very frequently.

Comment: since the problem persists if the pg_dump was taken from 95 or 10 should the title be revised to make that clear? "pg_restore of large tables in pg10 is super slow"

Comment: Any idea on which part it is spending so much time?  In any case, `shared_buffers`, `work_mem`, and `maintenance_work_mem` all seem to be very low.  If the slowness is coming from index creation, then increasing `maintenance_work_mem` to a few GBs can help.

Comment: How to find out which operation is taking more time in the whole restore process. Verbose logging of pg_restore doesn't really tell much.